# Apache Flink: How to group every n rows with the Table API?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

Recently I am trying to use Apache Flink for fast batch processing.
I have a table with a column:value and an irrelevant index column

Basically I want to calculate the mean and range of every 5 rows of value. Then I am going to calculate the mean and standard deviation based on those mean I just calculated. So I guess the best way is to use `Tumble` window.

It looks like this

```
DataSet<Tuple2<Double, Integer>> rawData = {get the source data};
Table table = tableEnvironment.fromDataSet(rawData);
Table groupedTable = table
            .window(Tumble.over("5.rows").on({what should I write?}).as("w")
            .groupBy("w")
            .select("f0.avg, f0.max-f0.min");

{The next step is to use groupedTable to calculate overall mean and stdDev}
```

But I don't know what to write in `.on()`. I have tried `"proctime"` but it said there is no such input. I just want it to group by the order as it reads from the source. But it has to be a time attribute so I cannot use `"f2"` - the index column as ordering as well.

Do I have to add a timestamp to do this? Is it necessary in batch processing and will it slow down the calculation? What is the best way to solve this?

**Update :**
I tried to use a sliding window in the table API and it gets me Exception.

```
// Calculate mean value in each group
    Table groupedTable = table
            .groupBy("f0")
            .select("f0.cast(LONG) as groupNum, f1.avg as avg")
            .orderBy("groupNum");

//Calculate moving range of group Mean using sliding window
    Table movingRangeTable = groupedTable
            .window(Slide.over("2.rows").every("1.rows").on("groupNum").as("w"))
            .groupBy("w")
            .select("groupNum.max as groupNumB, (avg.max - avg.min) as MR");
```

The Exception is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Count sliding group windows on event-time are currently not supported.
>
> at org.apache.flink.table.plan.nodes.dataset.DataSetWindowAggregate.createEventTimeSlidingWindowDataSet(DataSetWindowAggregate.scala:456)
>
> at org.apache.flink.table.plan.nodes.dataset.DataSetWindowAggregate.translateToPlan(DataSetWindowAggregate.scala:139)
>
> ...

Does that mean that sliding window is not supported in Table API? If I recall correctly there is no window function in DataSet API. Then how do I calculate moving range in batch process?

Answer (score 0):

The `window` clause is used to define a grouping based on a window function, such as `Tumble` or `Session`. Grouping every 5 rows is not well defined in the Table API (or SQL) unless you specify the order of the rows. This is done in the `on` clause of the `Tumble` function. Since this feature originates from stream processing, the `on` clause expects a timestamp attribute.

You can fetch the timestamp of the current time using the `currentTimestamp()` function. However, I should point out that Flink will sort the data as it is not aware of the monotonic property of the function. Moreover, all of that will with a parallelism of 1 because there is no clause that would allow for partitioning.

Alternatively, you can also implement a user-defined scalar function that converts the index attribute into a timestamp (effectively a Long value). But again, Flink will do a full sort of the data.

Comment: Thank you for answering! So in this case do you suggest that I should add an index column and convert it to long? Right now I am using zipWithIndex() in DataSet to apply index and assign group number to each row using self-defined flatMap function

Comment: I you are coming from the DataSet API, you might want to have a look at the `MapPartitionFunction` which can be used for this computation as well and would avoid the full sort. In that case, you would not need the Table API.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to convert my groupNumber from INTEGER to LONG and tried to use it as the time attribute in window. However I get this exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Count sliding group windows on event-time are currently not supported. Could you please suggest if I have written something wrong? I will post my code in the end of the question. Thank you

Comment: Oh, yes it seems that event-time count windows are not yet supported for batch Table API / SQL queries. I'd recommend to implement this using a `MapPartitionFunction` which should be much more efficient if the data is already sorted.